Why is this correlation coefficient given by pandas unrealistically low?
I am coding in python and I am correlating a row in pandas (index 2500) with a sinusoidal function that I defined (sine_modulation). When I print the value I obtain by using
row_correlation(saved_data_DAQ.iloc[2500].values, sine_modulation(time_measurement,modulation_frequency_axion))
where row_correlation(f,g) is just defined as np.corrcoef(f, g)[0, 1] I obtain 0.23. However, if I plot both functions I can visually see an extemely high degree of correlation (see image). This is expected because the blue curve is just random white noise (from a gaussian distribution) plus a constant times the sine modulation itself (blue = noise + C*red where C=0.002)
I would like to know why the correlation computed by this function is so low, but more importantly, do you have any idea or suggestion on how to compute a correlation that better reflects the high degree of correlation between my two functions?

You can also see zoom-in below

NOTE that it may as well be that the correlation is right and it is 0.23, then my question would be the following: what other quantity could I compute to show wether my noise has an oscillation component or not? I saw the word "synchronization" on the comments, maybe this is the right quantity to compute?

"extemely high degree of correlation" - in my opinion there is only some correlation.  0.23 seems legit given the amount of additinal components/noise in the blue signal. You have "very high degree of synchronization" though

Correlations are based on Z-scores, you've only added noise, not also subtracted it. I suspect if you added noise in both directions, your r value would be higher based on visual inspection.

Maybe better to scatter these two signals against each other, plotting them like this does not show you the full story, as dankal said, 0.23 seems to be in order.

Also, would help your cause to include the code that is generating this plot. Reproducible example and all that other stuff

It depends on the normalisation used but it looks to me like there is roughly an amplitude of ~0.25 of a sine wave component at the frequency that you are correlating against. Check sin(x) against sin(x) to determine the normalisation in use and/or set the noise to zero. You need to show us the code you used for this to be anything more than guesswork.

synchronization can be determined by cross-correlation. It is better if you answer the comments rather than editting the question

apply a local minimum kernel. that gives you the... "lower envelope" or whatever people might call it. in image processing, we call this a "grayscale" morphology operation, specifically erosion. if you need this demonstrated, provide the data or a piece of code to generate it. [mre]

I would be very interested in your input, can you use my toy signals as a starting point? I think they get quite close to the data in the question by OP @ChristophRackwitz

I did a short example for you to see where you are getting the low R values. Let's consider a pure positive sine:
N = 2500 # number of samples
t = np.linspace(0,1, N) # time going to 1 seconds I guess
Fs = N/t[-1] # sampling rate
sine = (np.sin(4*np.pi*t-np.pi/2)+1)/2 # positive sine wave

Since you did not add your code,I assumed your noise looks something like this:
noise = abs(np.random.normal(0,0.1,len(t))) # random 

Finally, let's define the coefficient you are multiplying the sine wave with. Let's set it as going from 0.001 to 1 in a linear space with 100 samples:
C = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 100) # pure sine coefficient

If we loop through those values and we generate the noisy signal with     sineWithNoise = c*sine + noise, we get the following results:

To know the actual value of c, look at the xlabel of the third subplot (the right most axes).
Most importantly, I think you need to see the scatter plot, as the calculation of the correlation coefficient relies on comparing the two signals against each other (source for image):

and not comparing the two signals in time against each other (source for image):

To use cross-correlation, you can use:
from scipy.signal import correlate, correlation_lags
xcorr = correlate(sine, sineWithNoise) # generated sineWithNoise = 0.2*sine + noise
lags = correlation_lags(N,N)/Fs # get lags in seconds
plt.figure()
plt.plot(lags, xcorr)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Lags (~s)") # xlabel
plt.ylabel("Cross-correlation") # ylabel
plt.axvline(0) # perfect scenario peak without any shift

To get the following results:

To get how well synchronised they are, you need to see if the maximum is indeed without any shift:
idxMax = np.argmax(xcorr) # get arg of maximum
print(lags[idxMax]) # print corresponding lag
# 0.0008, almost zero

Hope this helps you

Thank you so much Tino, this code is indeed a perfect minimal example of what I am doing... I now understand the difference between corrcoeff and cross correlation, so now it makes more sense to use the latter (which is basically the degree of synchronization, as was suggested on one comment, right?). I however do not know how to understand the last plot, because when I try with C=0, cross corr also has its maximum at ~0 with value ~100 (I cannot add images in the comment so maybe I will edit the original post including that). It seems as if the cross corr between pure noise and sine is high

Depending on what you want to do, the values of the cross-correlation can be either very very important or very unimportant. In case the absolute value of the cross-correlation are irrelevant, I recommend you normalize them. Check "cross-correlation normalization", there are plenty of examples. Check wiki also. If you are correlating the noise with itself, then this is an auto-correlation.
